# Отправка почты черезе gmail SMTP, phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, gmail

Создал тестовый аккаунт на gmail, подключил двухфакторную аутентификацию и создал пароль для приложения.

Пытаюсь через phpmailer отправить сообщения от тестового аккаунта, через девтулзы браузера вижу, что запрос уходит, но не вижу отправленных сообщений в gmail в папке "отправленные". Может кто-то знает в чем дело или рабочий способ отправки сообщений с сайта.

```
<?php 

 $name = $_POST['FIO'];
 $number = $_POST['number'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $city = $_POST['city'];

  require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
 $mail = new PHPMailer;
 $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

 // $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

 $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
 $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
 $mail->Username = 'test_login';                // Наш логин
 $mail->Password = 'my_key';                    // Наш пароль от приложения
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also  accepted
 $mail->Port = 465; //465                                    // TCP port to connect to

 $mail->setFrom('test.ru', 'Work');            // От кого письмо 
 $mail->addAddress('my_mail@list.ru');         // На какую почту отправлять письмо
 $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

 $mail->Subject = 'Данные';
 $mail->Body    = '
    Пользователь оставил данные <br> 
ФИО: ' . $name . ' <br>
Текст: ' . $number . '<br>
E-mail: ' . $email . '<br>
Город: ' . $city . '';

if(!$mail->send()) {
   return false;
} else {
   return true;
}

?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А письма приходят получаетялм или нет? То что писем нет в папке "Отправленные", это не значит что они не отправились. Они могут вообще не сохраняться, а могут сохраняться в другой папке.

Comment: писем нет нигде, ни у отправляемого аккаунта, ни у получаемого.

Comment: попробуйте метод IsSendmail
поле From должно быть с мылом существующего домена

Comment: @sterx, Да, это сработало, спасибо! Можешь оформить как правильный ответ, я сразу апрувну его)

Comment: То, что у вас статус 200 вообще ни о чем не говорит. Копайте проблему, дебажте функции и методы, которые в вашем smart.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте метод IsSendmail и поле From должно быть с мылом существующего домена